# Ngclick Upload button ceases working without trace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, angularjs-ng-click

Using angular-selenium-protractor. Select button and Uploading done via flow.js with ngclick as executor button.

ONLY Under protractor, Upload button ceases working when invalid internally formatted json file is selected, without visible changes in running html code after file is selected, what do? Need a failing testcase.

Answer (score 0):

Fml... the problem was, I misspelled the name of the invalid file in the disk differently as in the input filename string... so it appeared in the uploader via the path injection method, but was a non existent file.